# PHP simpler way than splitting a string

Tags: php

I wonder if there is a simpler, better, more efficient way to extract data from string than splitting it to pieces and storing those pieces in variables. For example I have a line which contains some / separated fields (note: not all of them are / separated).

/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/CN=Cliento/

I only need to grab the value of the CN field. For this what I do right now:

```
       preg_match('/\/CN=[a-z_\-0-9].*\//i', $line, $client3);
       $client2 = split('=', $client3[0]);
       $client1 = split('/', $client2[1]);
       print 'Client: '. $client1[0]."\n";
```

But I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-explode-dn.php

Comment: `$values = array(); parse_str(str_replace('/', '&', $line), $values); var_dump($values);`

Comment: This isn't specifically ldap format but a log file, the line also contains date with commas and other text. Just one part of it has couple of fields with / -s and even from those I only need one, the CN.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing two splits you could just return the section of the match you need using a substring:

```
$line = '/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/CN=Cliento/';
preg_match('/\/CN=[a-z_\-0-9].*\//i', $line, $matches);
echo substr($matches[0], 4, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this with a single regular expression. The following expression works fine:

```
/(?<=CN\=)[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+/
```

This reqular expression extracts everything after "CN=". It is also required that there is a "CN=" in the haystack.